# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.Profile.getFirstName()'

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am trying to fetch some data on my android validation using Facebook API. I am able to login into my facebook account. This is the permission I have set to fetch data from Facebook account

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList( "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
```

using the above permissions I am trying to fetch profile name and other data I am getting a null pointer exception with the below code snippet

```
public void getFacebookData(AccessToken accessToken, Profile profile) {
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("--Facebook Login Successful!");
        System.out.println("--Logged in user Details : ");
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("--User ID : " + accessToken.getUserId());
        System.out.println("--Authentication Token : " + accessToken.getToken());
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("--First Name : " + profile.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("--Last Name : " + profile.getLastName());
        System.out.println("--URL Perfil: " + profile.getLinkUri());
        System.out.println("--URL Imagem: " + profile.getProfilePictureUri(500, 500));
        System.out.println("---------------------");
        System.out.println("--ID : " + profile.getId());
        System.out.println("--Name : " + profile.getName());
        System.out.println("---------------------");

        TextView profile_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile);
        profile_name.setText(profile.getName());
```

Please, what be wrong with the approach I am using.

Comment: Obviously, **profile** is **null**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value .

**[getCurrentProfile()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Profile/)**

> Getter for the profile that is currently logged in to the application.

```
public void getFacebookData(AccessToken accessToken, Profile profile) {
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile(); // Add this 
   if (profile != null) 
   {
    System.out.println("--First Name : " + profile.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("--Last Name : " + profile.getLastName());
    System.out.println("--URL Perfil: " + profile.getLinkUri());
    System.out.println("--URL Imagem: " + profile.getProfilePictureUri(500, 500));
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    System.out.println("--ID : " + profile.getId());
    System.out.println("--Name : " + profile.getName());
    System.out.println("---------------------");

   }
```

Comment: profile still returns null does this has to do with the account I am using

Comment: @blend may be ! DEBUG please